# More than one instance of overloaded function

Tags: c++, compilation, cuda, clang

I am trying to compile a library that uses CUDA, on an Ubuntu system using CUDA 8.0 and clang 3.8.
The library includes `Eigen` headers in several `*.cu` files, which apparently includes the `cmath` header, causing an ambiguity in the CUDA headers.

```
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/cuda_fp16.h(3068): error: more than one instance of overloaded function "isinf" matches the argument list:
            function "std::isinf(float)"
            function "isinf(float)"
            argument types are: (float)
```

CUDA defines its own `__device__ ​ __RETURN_TYPE isinf ( float  a )`, and I would expect that `std::isinf` would have to be called explicitly rather than create a conflict.

Any leads on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As I recall, this is actually a Clang problem. Compiling in C++11 mode with Clang 3.8 and gcc 6 standard library headers will trigger the problem. If you switch to a supported gcc 5 version, or don't specify C++11 support, the problem will disappear.