# CUDA: more than one instance of overloaded function `isnan`

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda

I am getting an error while trying to compile CUDA code with the `-std=c++11` flag.

```
error: more than one instance of overloaded function "isnan" matches the argument list:
        function "isnan(float)"
        function "std::isnan(float)"
        argument types are: (r32)
```

(`r32` is a `typedef` for `float`)

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558411/more-than-one-instance-of-overloaded-function), in which the answer suggests to simply not specify C++11 to fix the problem, which I can not do because I am using some features of C++11 like `constexpr` and lambdas. Is there a way of compiling with C++11 features turned on, and still resolve this ambiguity?

I am using the following command to compile:

```
 nvcc -I/my/include/path/1 -I/usr/local/cuda/include src/myfile.cu -o build/myfile.o -arch=sm_61 -c --compiler-options -fPIC -Xcudafe -std=c++11
```

the compiler version is:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What CUDA version is this?

Comment: I updated the question. It is CUDA 8.0

Comment: There have been five release versions of the toolchain since CUDA 8. Have you considered testing a newer version?

Comment: I have in fact not tried. I'll install the newest version and see if it compiles.

Comment: I checked with version 10.0.130 and it seems to fix the problem. Thanks! If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this overload conflict problem was an issue with the CUDA 8 release compiler, it was fixed for the CUDA 9 release and anyone experiencing this issue should upgrade to CUDA 9 or newer.

[This answer was assembled from comments and added as a community wiki answer]

Comment: I'm using CUDA 11.6 and still get this error. However replacing `isnan` with `std::isnan` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770374/why-is-isnan-ambiguous-and-how-to-avoid-it) works for me.